# String Array problem in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I just started playing in scala. I got a method that accepts string array as input

```
def Lambdatest(args:Array[String]) = args.foreach(arg=>println(arg))
```

And i have create a string array like this

```
var arr=new Array[String](3) 
arr(0)="ram"
arr(1)="sam"
arr(2)="kam"
```

When i call **Lambdatest(arr)**, it throws an error like the below

```
scala> LambdaTest(arr)                       
<console>:7: error: not found: value LambdaTest
       LambdaTest(arr)
       ^
```

Whats the reason??

And is there a simple way to initialize the string arrays like the one in c#??

```
var strArr = new string[3] {"ram","sam","kam"};
```

Comment: Aside: In C#, the above array can be defined even more concisely as: `var strArr = new [] {"ram", "sam", "kam"};`

Comment: @Rahuλ G, yeah we can do that.. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your method definition and the invocation are not the same, you define `Lambdatest` yet invoke `LambdaTest`.

Additionally, you can define the array as:

```
val arr = Array("ram", "sam", "kam")
```

Your code will execute, providing you correct the method invocation:

```
scala> Lambdatest(arr)
ram
sam
kam
```